# reason: '-[FaveoHelpdeskPro_Swift.AppDelegate window]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x282efc980'

Tags: ios, swift, ios13

I am getting following error when I am trying to run the project, my project is crashing.

It is giving following error,

> FaveoHelpdeskPro_Swift[1400:370341]
>   -[FaveoHelpdeskPro_Swift.AppDelegate window]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x282efc980

and

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason:
>   '-[FaveoHelpdeskPro_Swift.AppDelegate window]: unrecognized selector
>   sent to instance 0x282efc980'

and it coming to following screen,

[image]

and my `SceneDelegate.swift` contains already window object,

```
class SceneDelegate: UIResponder, UIWindowSceneDelegate {

var window: UIWindow?

func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
    // Use this method to optionally configure and attach the UIWindow `window` to the provided UIWindowScene `scene`.
    // If using a storyboard, the `window` property will automatically be initialized and attached to the scene.
    // This delegate does not imply the connecting scene or session are new (see `application:configurationForConnectingSceneSession` instead).
    guard let _ = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }
}
```

what is the issue, why it is crashing ?

[Here is the complete project](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1cQo-ZUsvxXLdbSPbz49S9E_meBvDwNFA/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: add "var window: UIWindow?" in you AppDelegate and try.

Comment: put that window object in AppDelegate class
because some class is trying to access that window obj from appdel.

Comment: Great, its working now

Comment: Now, Did you get why is it crashing?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your `AppDelegate` does not contain a `window` reference. Add a `window` variable in your `AppDelegate`

```
var window: UIWindow?
```

An excerpt from Apple's [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1623056-window)

> This property contains the window used to present the app’s visual content on the device’s main screen.
>
> **Implementation of this property is required if your app’s Info.plist file contains the UIMainStoryboardFile key**

Comment: God bless you. You've save my life.

Answer (score 6):

When you start to init your main ViewController in SceneDelegate in the project and some UI libraries (like SVProgressHUD,...) still point to AppDelegate's `window` and nothing there, so it crashes. I have met and successfully fixed this problem following this way:

1. Declare an UIWindow in `AppDelegate` if it's not there, also declare a static variable for fast access to AppDelegate:

   ```
   @UIApplicationMain
   class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
       var window: UIWindow? // HERE, add it if it's not available.
       static var shared: AppDelegate { return UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate }
       //...
   }
   ```
2. In `SceneDelegate`, make a reference of UIWindow object back to AppDelegate:

   ```
   @available(iOS 13.0, *)
   class SceneDelegate: UIResponder, UIWindowSceneDelegate {

       var window: UIWindow? // HERE

       func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
           guard let windowScene = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }
           window = UIWindow(frame: windowScene.coordinateSpace.bounds)
           window?.windowScene = windowScene
           window?.rootViewController = YOUR_VIEW_CONTROLLER()
           window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
           AppDelegate.shared.window = window // Connect it HERE!
       }
       // ....
   }
   ```

Note: If you just finish step 1, it will not crash but some UI component will display wrong because they cannot determine which is the main Window.

Answer (score 0):

So what I just did is I added a UIWindow var to my AppDelegate like so:

```
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

...
```

Then in the SceneDelegate, when I am setting the UIWindow property:

```
class SceneDelegate: UIResponder, UIWindowSceneDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
        guard let windowScene = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }
        window = UIWindow(frame: windowScene.coordinateSpace.bounds)
        window?.rootViewController = MainTabBarController()
        window?.windowScene = windowScene
        window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

I also set it for the AppDelegate as well right below like so:

```
if let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate {
    appDelegate.window = window
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this error because of using SVProgressHUD, my solution is the same as @ngbaanh, defined a window variable in AppDelegate and got referenced to window in SceneDelegate